# How Do I Fix "Permission Denied" Error When Trying to Make Directory in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mkdir, permission-denied

when I type the command

```
mkdir rails_projects
```

to follow along with a tutorial I am using on www.railstutorial.org I get this problem:

```
~ DUFF$ mkdir rails_projects
mkdir: rails_projects: Permission denied
```

Does anyone know what this is happening? I tried to quit terminal and come back, but that didn't work. I was thinking I may some how not have access to the current directory I am in, but I am not sure how to check that and I am the only user (that I am aware of on the computer). I looked around at the other threads but it seemed like they were not the same issue and most were PHP based.

I am not sure what commands I use to find out the directory I am currently in. Also, I am new to programming so I am not sure where these things reside on my system. Any help would be appreciated. You all were very helpful with my questions yesterday. I have seen a few posts saying you never need to use sudo and I should have access to create a directory, so I am not sure what is happening.

Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: What operating system are you using? If it's Linux/OS X, you can use the `pwd` command to list your current directory. 

I would recommend you then switch directories to your user's home directory and start work there. You can do this with `cd ~`

Comment: Sweet mercy, I love this website. That worked. Just so I know and can learn, what does pwd stand for? I am assuming the "d" is directory.

Now I know the ~ is home directory. However, where exactly is the home directory? Is that simply user/___ in OS X (the system I use)?

Comment: How do I mark your answer as the one that solved the question?

Comment: @Matt pwd = present working directory. You can do `pwd` after `cd ~` to see what is the home directory of your user.

Comment: @Matthew Lehner you should post it as a answer so that op can accept and mark this question as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What operating system are you using? If it's Linux/OS X, you can use the `pwd` command to list your current directory.

I would recommend you then switch directories to your user's home directory and start work there. You can do this with the `cd ~`

`~` is simply a shortcut for the full path to the user's home directory, which, in OS X is generally /Users/username